# How to define a problem which involves iterating over the input?

Tags: notation

Lets say I have a simple continuous function f with X,Y pairs. Lets assume there is a target value which is know and not necessarily on the curve. What we would like to do is iterate through the x values between certain bounds to find where the output is closest to this target value and ultimately return the best x value.

Now, my question is, how can we define this equation mathematically?

Comment: I gave my answer below, but your question is not very clear. It is not clear what you mean by “iterate through the x values”. In your very last line, it is not clear what you mean by “this equation”, as I don’t see you talking about equations in the premise. Is that the equation that the minimizer $x_0$ has to satisfy? Or the equation that defines the iterative algorithm?

Comment: Hi lorenzo, thank you for the feedback. Ideally we are looking for the input value which will result in the closest output to the target value. By iterate i mean searching the whole domain within particular bounds. This is an attempt to find a mathematical way of expressing an algorithm. If there is a better way of stating this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression for the set of "best $x$ values" you're referring to is $\arg\min_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-T|$. See [arg max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max).

Comment: Is this what you're looking for, or did you really want to express an iterative algorithm?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what im looking for :) making the assumption that there is only one value returned and what is returned is the x that im looking for

Comment: Yeah, I've seen $\arg\min(...)$ used as a single value, even though this isn't well-defined in general since there may be multiple.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have $y_0\in Y$ and you want to minimize the quantity $F(x):=d(f(x),y_0)$ and return the best $x$ value.

If $f$ is a regular curve, say $X=\mathbb R$ and $Y=\mathbb R^n$ (besides degenerate cases, e.g. assuming that there actually exists a minimizer) then, if we call $x_0$ the minimizer, it has to satisfy

$$\langle f’(x_0),y_0-f(x_0)\rangle=0.$$

To solve the problem (analitically) starting from a random point $x_1$, you just define the curve $\gamma(t)$ which solves the initial value problem

$$ \gamma’(t)=-\nabla F(\gamma(t)), $$
$$ \gamma(0)=x_1,$$

where $F(x)$ is defined above (this is called “gradient flow equation “if I am not wrong). Then (under certain hypotheses and, again, excluding degenerate cases) you should hope to have

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\gamma(t)=x_0.$$

So, if you want to build an iterative method, the natural thing to do is try to mimic the behaviour of $\gamma$. To do this, you use an Eulerian scheme. Fix $h>0$. Define iteratively

$$x_n:=x_{n-1}-h\nabla F(x_{n-1})$$

and, if $h$ is small enough, it should hold

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x_0$$.

I don’t want to repeat myself, this is not working 100% of times. You need some hypotheses on the problem to ensure that the limit exists and you might need to choose $x_1$ with a grain of salt. Moreover, if the sequence converges, the limit point should be a point that satisfies the first equation that I wrote. It is not guaranteed that it is a local minimizer of $F$, let alone a GLOBAL minimizer of $F$.